# SPRING BATCH Execution with 2 modes

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a requirement to execute a job with 2 modes using a parameter to distinguich betwwen the 2 modes .for example if the user use the parameter X in this case the job must read the data from the database and export it (all the records ) to an xml file.Otherwise if the user uses the parameter Y in this case the job must write each record in a separate xml file using the same header.

Comment: You could create 2 different jobs, and call job1 for X or job2 for Y

Comment: Thanks for your reply,How can i call a job 1 for X for example ?

Comment: `if("X".equals(param)) { Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("job-for-X"); }`

Answer (score 2):

Use jobParameter to distinguish the modes:

```
@StepScope
@Bean
public Tasklet task(@Value("#{jobParameters['mode']}") String mode) {
}
```

If the modes are so different then you can't do them in same step, use decider:

```
FlowBuilder<Flow> flowBuilder = new FlowBuilder<>("modesFlow");

Flow flow = flowBuilder
        .start(modesDecider)
        .on("X")
        .to(step1)      
        .from(modesDecider)
        .on(step2)
        .end()
        .build();

jobBuilderFactory.get("modesJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())        
        .start(flow)
        .end()
        .build();
```

where:

```
ModesDecider implements JobExecutionDecider
```